# Not displaying Sprite created with class

Tags: c++, sfml

I created a class for my pickups, in my Pickup.h. 
This would be:

```
class Pickup
{
private:
    Sprite m_Sprite;
    int m_Value;
    int m_Type;
public:
Pickup (int type)
{
    m_Type = type;
    if (m_Type == 1)
    {
        Sprite m_Sprite;
        Texture health;
        health.loadFromFile("health.png");
        m_Sprite.setTexture(health);
    }
    else ...

}
void spawn()
{
    srand((int)time(0) / m_Type);
    int x = (rand() % 1366);
    srand((int)time(0) * m_Type);
    int y = (rand() % 768);
    m_Sprite.setPosition(x, y);
}
Sprite getSprite()
{
    return m_Sprite;
}
};
```

If I try to draw on the screen a Sprite created with this class, using

```
Pickup healthPickup(1);
healthPickup.spawn();
```

before entering the game loop, and inside the game loop to put

```
    mainScreen.draw(healthPickup.getSprite());
```

I never get to see that Sprite on the screen. I tried to make another Sprite using

```
Sprite m_Sprite2;
Texture health2;
health2.loadFromFile("health.png");
m_Sprite2.setTexture(health2);
m_Sprite2.setPosition(healthPickup.getSprite().getPosition().x, healthPickup.getSprite().getPosition().y);
```

and if I try to display it in the game loop, everything works just fine. My question is: why this doesn't work with my created class?

Comment: nvm look at your constructor, you are creating a sprite named m_sprite instead of just setting your m_sprite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be:

```
class Pickup
{
private:
    Sprite m_Sprite;
    int m_Value;
    int m_Type;
public:
Pickup (int type)
{
    m_Type = type;
    if (m_Type == 1)
    {
        Texture health; // removed the declaration of m_Sprite that was here.
        health.loadFromFile("health.png");
        m_Sprite.setTexture(health);
    }
    else ...

}
void spawn()
{
    srand((int)time(0) / m_Type);
    int x = (rand() % 1366);
    srand((int)time(0) * m_Type);
    int y = (rand() % 768);
    m_Sprite.setPosition(x, y);
}
Sprite getSprite()
{
    return m_Sprite;
}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

From the constructor:

```
Pickup (int type)
{
    m_Type = type;
    if (m_Type == 1)
    {
        Sprite m_Sprite;
        ...
```

Here you define a *local variable* with the same name as the member variable. This creates a local variable that will go out of scope and be destructed.

The constructor leaves the member variable uninitialized.

---

To solve your problem *properly* there are two changes you need to make: The first is to construct the member variable `m_Sprite`. The second is to not define the local variable.

Something like this:

```
Pickup (int type)
    : m_Sprite()    // Constructor initializer list, default-constructs the m_Sprite member
{
    m_Type = type;
    if (m_Type == 1)
    {
        // Don't define a local variable m_Sprite
        Texture health;
        health.loadFromFile("health.png");
        m_Sprite.setTexture(health);
    }
    ...
}
```